# React Native App crashes on android 11 on launch without giving error

Tags: android, reactjs, crash, native, launch

[image]

this is my build.gradle setting and this is my system info
[image]

I'm trying to run the react native app on android 11 but it is keep crashing on launch without giving any error I have tries almost every solution including setting in build.gradle

```
buildToolsVersion = "30.0.0"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 30
targetSdkVersion = 30
supportLibVersion = "30.0.0"
ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
multiDexEnabled = true
```

setting ** target API to"30" ** in AndroidManifest.xml

the Gradle version I'm using is
Gradle plugin version is 4.1.3
Gradle version is 6.7**

please help me find the solution in this regard thanks

Answer (score 12):

I got an error like this when setting targetSdk version to `30` it's happening because of okhttp version and fixed it by using the latest version

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1")
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:4.9.1")
```

add this in your `android/app/build.gradle`

Comment: Where in the bundle should I add this?

Comment: The way is not update the okhttp version. Just update react-native version. This issue was solved in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/29741
To update react-native version you can use:
    npx react-native upgrade

Comment: @RogerCruz you should add this in your `android/app/build.gradle`, I have mentioned this in the answer

Comment: @JulianCorrêa, This issue was happening in the latest stable react native, You have mentioned about an old PR which was increasing okhttp to version 3 but with this issue you need to increase it to version 4

Comment: @Gigarthan About the PR, you're right. So, I build a app and sent to production a few days ago using RN 0.66.3, and this issue was solved. I didnt any change about okhttp. Change the version of libs that are used inside of core of react is not a good solution, but some times its necessary, in this case you must inform that solution is temporary, palliative. Am I wrong? 
I just test (debug and release) right now a fresh new project on my Device with Android 11 and there is no crash anymore.

Comment: For me works with implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.2")

Answer (score 7):

This answer has been provided by manohar-octifi ([github discussion](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30366#issuecomment-927219602)):

If you are using @sentry/react-native and the version is lower than 2.0.0, then update the version to 2.0.0 or higher (I updated to 2.2.0). This should fix the problem.

Comment: You saved my life, I was using an old Sentry version. Thank you!

Comment: I am very glad to hear! :)