# React Native android application crashing on Android 11 after targetSDk changed to 30

Tags: android, react-native, crash, targetsdkversion

I changed targetSDK version to 30 to be in compliance with the play store.
The app is crashing immediately at launch. Tried every solution on StackOverflow and GitHub.
Note: app works on Android 9 and below.

Logs I am getting from logcat,

```
/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so
E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes-executor-release.so
E/GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported get request. Object with ID '108xxxxxxxxx' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}
A/libc: /Users/willholen/intern/hermes/include/hermes/VM/HermesValue.h:195: static hermes::vm::HermesValue hermes::vm::HermesValue::encodeNativePointer(const void *): assertion "(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(p) & ~kDataMask) == 0 && "Native pointer must contain zeroes in the high bits"" failed
 A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 22840 (mqt_js), pid 22732 (angle.traveller)
```

Comment: `project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]`.  If I make enableHermes to false. app is working fine. But crashes again using true. Since I want benefits of hermes, I can't turn it to false.

Answer (score 0):

Update okhttp3 Like in the answer bellow:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68744493/7668448

or your sentry dependency:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70049868/7668448

Basically you need to make sure the dependencies are updated and support the target sdk 30.

You can see more details here:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30366

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have already tried and tested updating  okhttp3 and sentry but the app is still crashing on Android 11 devices without any crashlog.  But as you said that check all dependencies are updated and support targeted 30, this I will try and check, Thanks again for your advice.